# Vercel Node version incompatibility (Node, npm)

Tags: node.js, npm, vercel

I installed *'react-bidirectional-infinite-scroll'* but it seems to be using node v9/8 and when I deploy the project over vercel it throws

```
error react-bidirectional-infinite-scroll@2.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^9.2.0 || ^8.0.0". Got "12.20.1"
error Found incompatible module.
```

I tried as someone suggested to place the following inside package.json:

```
"engines" : {
    "node" : "<=9.2.0"
  },
  "engineStrict" : true,
```

but then the error becomes

```
Error: Found `engines` in `package.json` with a discontinued Node.js version range..etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `react-bidirectional-infinite-scroll` is unmaintained. See this [related issue](https://github.com/eberhara/react-bidirectional-infinite-scroll/issues/17).

You can try to set your [Install Command](https://vercel.com/docs/build-step#install-command) to `yarn install --ignore-engines` and hope it works correctly with newer Node.js versions, but its probably best to swap that dependency for something that supports Node.js 12 or 14.